# saving information to database from webform

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users ". "(first_name,last_name,dob,mobile_number,landline_number,email) ". "VALUES('$fname','$sname','$dob','$mobile','$landline','$email', NOW())";
$query = "INSERT INTO address ". "(house_number,street_name,town/city,postcode,province/county) ". "VALUES('$hnumber','$addr','$town','$pcode','$county', NOW())";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query 2"); // runs query using open connection
```

So I can create a connection to my database no problem and on my previous page I can send username and password to the database but then I come to the user details page to save the information and continually getting Invalid query 2 error. The table names are correct (users & address) and all variables are spelt correctly. Does anyone have a suggestion to fix the issue or a better alternative (I mean to just point me in the right direction of the research I should be looking at if I am way off target, if I have just mispelled something or have something in the wrong place then I would appreciate the heads up, have been at this quite a while now)

This is the code from the previous page and it works fine and sends the information to the database:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO login ". "(username,password) ". "VALUES('$uname','$epass', NOW())";// sets up sql query
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query 2"); // runs query using open connection

mysqli_close($conn); // close database connection
```

As far as I know all the database side of things is fine, all data types are varchar except for dob which is date (I have tried changing this to varchar to see if it fixed the problem but it didnt) and userID is int and is an autoincrement for the unique primary key. I have also tested the php file without the validation rules and still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a few things wrong here.

First you are reassigning the variable $query; so the first insert will be getting overwritten by the second, you need to concat the variable.

Then you have 2 queries you are attempting to send at one time. However you never tell Sql you've finished your first before starting your second.

Try the following instead take note Of The semi colons `;` at the end of each.

You are also putting slashes into your column names which is illegal.

Lastly, you've got more values to insert than you have columns. Remove the now() from the end.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users ". "(first_name,last_name,dob,mobile_number,landline_number,email) ". "VALUES('$fname','$sname','$dob','$mobile','$landline','$email');"; 
$query .= "INSERT INTO address ". "(house_number,street_name,town_city,postcode,province_county) ". "VALUES('$hnumber','$addr','$town','$pcode','$county');";
```

Although this will now work, I highly recommend you do some research regarding safe practices with Sql.

Here would be a great starting point https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

On a side note, why are you concating your Strings? There's no need

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (first_name,last_name,dob,mobile_number,landline_number,email)  VALUES('$fname','$sname','$dob','$mobile','$landline','$email', NOW());";
```

Comment: I don't know if you have read it wrong or if I have misunderstood your meaning (I really apologise if that's the case). But I already have semi colons at the end of each

Comment: You have them at the end of each PHP statement, not within your Sql however.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's the fact that you are closing the connection after your first call.

Comment: I have it reopened again on the second page, apologies, I should have included that

Answer (score -1):

try `or die(mysqli_error($conn));`

---

**EDIT:**
Delete passing value "NOW()".

code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO address ". "(house_number,street_name,town_city,postcode,province_county) ". "VALUES('$hnumber','$addr','$town','$pcode','$county')";
```

Comment: So I tried this and have to say thank you because it has at least narrowed down the problem, It was picking up the '/' and breaking the code so I have changed them to underslashes and have now got this error:   Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: @MrE if you don't have such column where to store value "NOW()", then don't pass it... delete last passing value and test it